# JUnit, test and threads

Tags: java, unit-testing, multithreading, junit

when i run multiple JUnit tests in a row, does JUnit create a new thread for each execution or everything is wrapped in a single thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all on a single thread. You don't say how you're invoking the tests, but for example, running a TestSuite will run all the tests in the suite sequentially.

If you want parallel execution, TestNG has support for running tests concurrently, as does [JUnitPerf](http://clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html) and [GroboUtils](http://groboutils.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: JUnit is also experimenting with parallel execution (search for the word parallel in the link): http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=675664&group_id=15278

Comment: Also, when you run in a Maven build, you can have each JUnit test set run in it's own environment - not just it's own thread.

Answer (score 3):

JUnit 4.0 supports concurrent tests