# JUnit4: Testing System.out in multiple test methods

Tags: java, junit4, system.out

I have an application where I want to write unit tests to test the output, written to System.out (and perhaps System.err).
Each individual test works as expected, however when adding multiple tests in the same class some tests fail because JUnit4 appears to be multi-threaded (thus no guarantees exists on when exactly the stream is reset).
The same happens when I separate all test methods in their own class and use a test suite.

Any ideas?

```java
private static final PrintStream SYS_OUT = System.out;
private static final PrintStream SYS_ERR = System.err;

private final ByteArrayOutputStream outContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private final ByteArrayOutputStream errContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

@Before
public final void setUpStreams() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(this.outContent, true, CHARSET));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(this.errContent, true, CHARSET));
}

@After
public final void cleanUpStreams() {
    System.setOut(SYS_OUT);
    System.setErr(SYS_ERR);
}

@Test
public final void listServicesAndMethods() throws ServiceException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    com.example.Main.main(new String[]{"--list-services"});
    LOG.debug(this.outContent.toString(CHARSET));
    assertTrue("String not found", this.outContent.toString(CHARSET).contains("Some string"));
    assertFalse("Other string found", this.outContent.toString(CHARSET).contains("Some other string"));
    this.outContent.reset();
    this.errContent.reset();
}
```

***Edit:*** It turns out that the issue with the failing tests was not (just?) because of the streams, but due to the fact that I stored the options in static fields in my main class. This has the effect that several options stay active during consecutive tests. I realised that after implementing Arian's suggestion, I then used the second class as an instance, instead of calling static methods, thus solving my issue.

Thanks to all who replied.

Comment: How do you know that JUnit is multithreaded? Because it certainly isn't in my environment. If you get console output that appears to be overlapping, that might just be a problem of buffer flushing.

Comment: As I understand it, the multi-threaded nature was added in JUnit 4. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789710/junit-test-and-threads  The issue does not appear to be buffer flushing, calling System.out.flush() before checking the contents has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not already done so, rewrite the parts of your application to take the output as a parameter, instead of writing directly to `System.out`. This is usually better design regardless of testing.

In each test, create a **new** output stream (or [spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) on `System.out` if you must) and pass it to the code unit under test.

Comment: How would I do that (using the parameter) the method that is being tested here is `public static void main(String[] args)`.  This method calls a private method to parse the command line options and set some fields accordingly. Then the main method uses those fields to determine what to do. (This is also the only class using System.out directly.

Comment: create a second method that takes an output stream as additional parameter. Your old main now does one thing: calling this method, passing `System.out` and `args` as arguments. Your tests will be for the new method.

Comment: Ah, of course. Although it seems a bit dumb to do that just because of the tests. I figured out why the tests were failing, turns out it wasn't (just?) because of the threading, I'll edit the question to reflect that. You answered my question satisfactory, although I actually asked the wrong question, so I'll mark it as correct anyway.